# Error in translating the Excel file using Boto3(AWS)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have an excel file containing data with various data types.I want to translate the some specific columns with datatype object using boto3.
I am enclosing screenshot of my excel file.
[Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/608s5.png)

```
df = pd.read_excel('file_1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1',na_filter= False
col=df.columns

data_types=df.dtypes
print((len(data_types)))

for x in range(len(data_types)):
    print(x)
    print(data_types[x])
    if data_types[x]  =='object':


        df_new = pd.read_excel('file_1.xlsx','Sheet1',  usecols [x],header=None).astype(str)
        print(df_new)

        translate = boto3.client(service_name='translate',aws_access_key_id=<>, aws_secret_access_key=<>, region_name=<>, use_ssl=True)
        df_new = df_new.apply(lambda text: translate.translate_text(Text=str(text), SourceLanguageCode='en', TargetLanguageCode='de')['TranslatedText'])
```

output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB7aT.png)

Comment: The boto3 docs say that the Text parameter to translate_text() must be a string. You are populating this parameter with df_new which is the result of a call to Pandas read_excel(), which returns a DataFrame. A DataFrame is not a string.

Comment: Okay. But I have read excel as string in df_new.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to edit the code?

Comment: Apologies, I did not scroll far enough right and mistakenly assumed that the variable you named df_new was a DataFrame. I can't see your source data but what does df_new evaluate to?

Comment: df_new is column from excel sheet, i.e, Sheet1.

Comment: The code as written in your question is not valid (it has a couple of basic errors which prevent it running). Please correct the code so that it actually runs. Then please print out type(df_new) and add that to the question - in my tests, astype(str) does not always convert a DataFrame to a string.

Comment: Yeah. I agree with you. I have made changes in my code and I am able to solve the translation issue by type casting . But now, after translating the dataframe ,df_new is destroyed. A single line is being returned in df_new which contains data of all the columns of dataframe.

Comment: I have enclosed the screenshot of output. Just  check.